# How Android system time is reset after device's power is plugged out

Tags: android, time, system, factory, reset

I'm working with a device with a custom version of Android 4.2.
This device doesn't contain a battery at all, and work only on AC adapter.

After each AC adapter plugout, the system time is reset to a specific point of time (kind of factory time). Then after the device connects to internet successfully, system time will be synchronized with internet time.

My question is that, is this a normal behavior of Android? If yes, then is there any method to get that "factory time" value programmatically?

Comment: Im pretty sure its a normal behavior for absolutely any electronic device. Even old mobile phone gonna act the same way. I'm not sure there is some method to get the factory default time - usually it depends on device release date or firmware release date, etc.

Comment: **"...is this a normal behavior of Android?"** : It's normal behaviour for any hardware which has a clock but doesn't have battery-backup. Your question is a bit like "is it normal for it to go dark when I switch off the light in a room?". The "factory time" you refer to will be the base-line time of the clock chip - in many cases (although not all) this will be 1st Jan 1980 00:00:00 UTC. Also, why would you want that "factory time" base-line? It's of no use to you without reference to real-time - that's why the clock is sync'd at successful network connection.

Comment: Yes, I know that a little silly question, but asked just for sure. By the way, I heard that in some device there's an auxiliary power to feed the system clock, so as that the synchronized time can remain even after the AC adapter is plugged out. Correct me if that's wrong. I'm developping an app for the hardware, and must detect whether the factory time has been synchronized with internet time or not, so my current solution is check system time with "factory time" value.

Comment: @giang.asl.8: where have you reached with this ? have you seen my answer ?

Comment: I find this question interesting, regarding to unit testing of time dependant features: if I know that time cannot be set below a given time, I can limit my tests.

Answer (score 2):

If it has no battery, then it cannot maintain time using a real-time clock chip. So yes, that's normal in the sense that without a battery or backup power of any kind, it would be impossible for it to maintain time without external power or network connectivity.